# Laravel: Error found - [23000] : Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

Facing this error There is no column `'name'` in my table.
These are the fields in my table.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'cat_id',
    'location_id',
    'content',
];
```

Comment: apparently something has a column named `name` and it can't be null

Comment: good. go ahead and check database migration file as well

Comment: Check Laravel Migration of this table. Or check collumns of the table by phpMyAdmin

Comment: I checked, there is no column of this name in my table.

Comment: show us code where the point you reach this

Comment: @Er.MukeshSharma again ... some table has a column named `name` and it can't be null ... you assuming which table it is, is obviously wrong

Comment: public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have **name** attribute in your table. If the table is created using migration there might be a default attribute **name** which you did't noticed it when you create a schema or if you don;t need a **name** field you can remove from your migration table.

Answer (score 0):

laravel project default create filename with user.php
kindly check migration file and make sure that file is accessing model is exists or not.
sometimes we get error on file but that actually belongs to some other contents.

Answer (score 0):

Add value nullable in migration file

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your table add `$table->string('name')->nullable();`

to migration file and migrate again.